# Questions about removing enrollment from Chromebooks

Tags: discussion, questions

I can see that more and more questions about this topic are posted on Super User or Unix & Linux. It usually goes like this:

> Someone bought a used Chromebook online (eBay, Amazon Marketplace, Craigslist, …) but the device is enrolled to the Chromebook for [Enterprise](https://enterprise.google.com/chrome/devices/#chromebooks) or [Education](https://edu.google.com/k-12-solutions/chromebooks/) environment and cannot be used like a privately owned Chromebook.

For reference here is what the [support page](https://support.google.com/chromebook/answer/183084?hl=en) says:

> ## Reset a work or school Chromebook
>
> If you're using your Chromebook at work or school, you can't reset it.
>   Ask your administrator to wipe the data on your Chromebook and
>   re-enroll the device on your work or school network.

From my point of view any modification to these devices is very likely to be illegal (as in computer fraud, sabotage or possession of stolen goods), so such questions should better be closed and a **recommendation** be given to the OP **to return the device**.

I'm aware that there is a slight chance of sloppy managed enrolled devices being sold online, enrollment though should be removed when the device can be kept after leaving the organization in question—thus weaken the argument of spying on users. No customer should have to deal with this nor should sites like Stack Exchange and other communities.

In case of an **employee or student of the respective organization** being unhappy with the device being enrolled s/he **should contact the respective administrator or contact person** of the organization instead of asking for hacking advice. A clear distinction between company/organization property and privately owned may also help here understanding why things are as they are.

Cross-posted to U&L: https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/q/4634/49853

Comment: hmm, How would "You can't, cause these devices are locked to a specific organisation" and closing them as dupes work? I mean, in theory this might be similar to the hackintosh policy here but the simplest answer is "You can't cause foo". This would also be less confusing, since everyone is talking about the same thing, and we can throw a community FAQ as the master close target.

Comment: I think we agree (yes it's similar to hackintosh). Whatever works best here.

Comment: (Can you update on U&L?)

Answer (score 14):

After a lot of thinking - My opinion is that its actually going to be a lot simpler to have a canonical answer posted with a *hypothetical* or real case (I'm sure we can find one!) of someone needing to do this, picking it, and making it a community FAQ.

While I do suppose we *could* use our decision on hackintoshes as precedent having a single answer that goes "You can't according to google, and its plausible if you bought it, the machine might be stolen or misconfigured, and you *need* the organisation to fix it" is an actually acceptable answer.

*Unlike* hackintoshes, this is narrowly scoped and can be handled as dupes rather than closing as site policy.

Most hacking answers will be terrible and link outside I suspect and we can nuke em, or handle the answer as needed.

This is simple, dosen't need special cases, and using community FAQs seems *right* to me.

Comment: If/when a canonical is created for this, can we link it here for reference and to aid in finding the right dupe?

Comment: Yup. We should and I'd edit my answer to fit